# Checksum on the message

Tags: messaging

I'm a beginner with this.

In my project I need to calculate a two-digit 256modulo checksum, how do Icalculate this? Or can I implement some other checksum algorithm that is better?

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to look into [HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC) using, for instance, SHA-1 or SHA-256

Comment: Here is the deal.I recive message with the checksum in it.But in my application i need to check that checksum.

Comment: Then you have to provide more details on how the checksum is calculated in order for anyone to help you.

Comment: I got a message wich has checksum at the end(it is two digit 256modulo checksum).When i revice message i need to calculate checksum for the same message i see if it is the same as the checksum in the message.

Comment: Only thing I need to now is how to calculate two-digit 256modlo checksum.

Comment: For example, the Intel object file specification calls for a one byte checksum at the end of every record in the file. This checksum is stored in the last byte of each record and is defined to be the two's compliment of the sum of the values of all other bytes in the record modulo 256. That is, the sum of all bytes in a record modulo 256 added to the checksum byte's value should yield a value of zero. If it does not, either the checksum byte or some other byte in the record must have been corrupted. http://www.fearme.com/misc/alg/node184.html Doesn't, actually, help to answer the question.